# How do I remove myself from a project in the Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-compute-engine

I have several projects in the Google Developer Console where I am only a viewer. Can I remove myself from them, or hide them?

Comment: If you read this, please, add your comment [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35889152)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

At present, once you've accepted an invitation to view a project, you can't remove yourself from the project, as **Project User Management is the owner's / owners' exclusive right**. By extension, these projects can't be removed from / hidden in your Developers Console neither.

What you wish to accomplish goes through contacting the individual project's owners, and request they remove your access.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4593) issue on the App Engine bug tracker, which was marked as Acknowledged in 2011, but never acted on.

Comment: If you read this, please, add your comment [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35889152)

Comment: Wouldn't this be breaking GDPR rules in Europe?

Comment: This is a very annoying and stupid rule. What if I do not want to contact someone? It looks like a slavery rule. Isn't it?

Comment: Just stuck with this issue. I no longer in contact with project owner, and the project still on my list

Comment: What if the Project Owner doesnt reply anymore?

Comment: ok. this is ridiculous! i even doubt the account owner is alive currently. he was gone several years ago. so i'm stuck forever with this dead account?

Answer (score 7):

In this situation i contacted with google support team using live chat and after few minute they mailed me that they have removed me from it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how you ended up a member of a project, it can sometimes be due to being a member of a Google Group – see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70541593/1915961). You can find what groups you're a member of, using this [Google Groups link](https://groups.google.com/my-groups?pli=1). Leaving any groups you don't want to be a member of any more is a quick and easy step that fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score -3):

I asked for help. Here is this online form:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp

Some days later someone removed me from the project and send me an mail telling me *'my issue was resolved'*

Comment: This is not an answer, Better off as a comment