# google play developer console leave shared account

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

I faced a poblem with google play developer console.
Some times ago I was invited to share account in console, but now when I try to view this account I have a message "Developer account is invalid" but this account is in my "shared accounts" list. So the question is, how to leave this account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove myself from a project in the Google Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588640/how-do-i-remove-myself-from-a-project-in-the-google-developer-console)