# How to remove myself from a Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I decided to try Firebase. When I go to the console, I not only see my own project, but two projects that I never created or was supposed to have access to:

[image: Firebase console]

Those projects seem to be created by a "Rohit Travel & Tours". I can see some of the details:

[image: Project information]

When I go to Google Cloud's resource manager, sure enough, the project is also there, along with a few "My First Project" projects that seem to belong to the same people:

[image: Google Cloud resource manager]

I'm not sure why I got access to this. It's either a dangerous bug, or a clueless admin that added one of my emails to the project.

I'd like to remove that project since it's just clutter. However, I can't find a way to *remove myself* from the project, and since I don't have any kind of admin access, there's nothing I can actually change there. In fact, I can't find my account listed on any of the role/member fields either, so I'm not sure what's the real story there.

So far the admin emails listed on the accounts have been unresponsive when I requested that my account be removed.

There's no way to contact Google Cloud to request that either. Apparently the only way to contact them is with a paid support account of some kind.

So my question is: is there a way for me to ever remove myself from these accounts, so I don't see them on my panels, especially the Firebase dashboard?

Or am I stuck with these app accounts forever?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and I am on the same project.

Comment: Just quit that group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/atlassian-sourcetree-beta and problem solved. https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2016/03/25/sourcetree-beta-program-is-here-become-a-trusted-tester/

Comment: @DaniloDeQueiroz that's what the answer below says.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When such projects show up for me, it's usually because someone added a group that I'm a member of (like `all@company.com`) as a collaborator to that project. If that is the cause, there is no way to remove me/you as an individual user. One of the owners on the project will have to remove the overly broad group, and replace it by either a better targeted group or by the individual users.

Also see:

- [How do I remove myself from a project in the Google Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588640/how-do-i-remove-myself-from-a-project-in-the-google-developer-console)

Comment: Thank you so much. You nailed it - the bright admin added the "Atlassian Sourcetree Beta Group" email to the project, and therefore I had access to it. I left the  group (didn't even know it was still a thing, vaguely remember joining it a long time ago), and bam, project is gone from Firebase and GC Resource Manager. Poor  beta testers who ran into the same thing.

Comment: Another painful life experience brought on by my use of SourceTree. It's so funny to think that every person in that group will suffer the same experience where at first glance it looks like your account has been compromised. Thank you so much for providing some insight and a resolution.