# Projects under No Organization that cannot be accessed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the cloud-resource-manager page, there are 2 projects listed under `No organization`, one of them curiously has the id `you-can-see-this-project`, the other looks like an automatically generated project with the prefix **My Project xxx**.

The issue is that there seems to be no way to access these 2 projects even though I can see them under my account. The IAM page shows that I do not have the permission `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy` and every other page or action notes some missing permission.

Is there a way to shutdown/delete these projects or a way to remove myself from these projects?

Edit:
Seems like the 2 projects that are showing up in my account are the same with other people that have the same issue.

They are [image]

**Update (20221114):** Checked recently and both the rogue projects are gone with no action on our part. Probably it was finally cleaned-up?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. This issue was reported to (not directly related) eclipse plugin issue tracker as well here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3654

Comment: @viktor , thanks for linking. We are having the exact same ghost projects linked to our account.

Answer (score 4):

### Root cause

Your Google Cloud Account is subscribed to "google-appengine@googlegroups.com".

### Solution

Unsubscribing from this group will remove these projects. See [Google Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/46608) for reference.

---

I got this feedback directly from the Google Cloud Support team and confirmed it working on with my account. I did not consciously subscribe to that group, maybe this happens or happened automatically in the past. Also why these ghost projects are added remains a mystery to me, no idea what they should be used for. Here's hoping that Google will fix this in the future...

Comment: This actually works!!! Wow. Thank you. Bogus entries under No Organization are gone!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the Projects' members that have the Owner role; I think that there is not a specific IAM permission that permits Project deletion but that some identities must have the Owner role.

I suspect (!) you can't orphan Projects by removing the last Owner, so there must be at least one.

If you're unable to determine Ownership, Google Cloud Support can determine the Owners for you though I suspect Support won't be able to disclose this information to you but will need to contact the Owners directly about this.

Comment: I do not know who the owners are, will try reaching out to support to remove myself from the projects.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way I can reach them without buying a support package.

Comment: It is impossible to determine who the owners are, as IAM & Admin page for the project shows the error `You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account and associated it with a domain, your organization resource will be automatically created for you. The resource will be provisioned at different times depending on your account status:

- If you are new to Google Cloud and have not created a project yet,
  the organization resource will be created for you when you log in to
  the Google Cloud console and accept the terms and conditions.
- If you are an existing Google Cloud user, the organization resource
  will be created for you when you create a new project or billing
  account. Any projects you created previously will be listed under "No
  organization", and this is normal. The organization resource will
  appear and the new project you created will be linked to it
  automatically. You will need to move any projects you created under
  "No organization" into your new organization resource. For
  instructions on how to move your projects, see [Migrating projects
  into an organization.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing)

Users can only view and list projects they have access to via IAM roles. The Organization Administrator can view and list all projects in the organization.

The **No organization** option in the **Organization** drop-down lists the following projects:

- Projects that do not belong to the Organization yet.
- Projects for which the user has access to, but are under an
  Organization to which the user does not have access.

Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) for more information on creating and managing organizations.

Comment: I do not have any access privileges against these projects and I do not know who the owners are.

Comment: To confirm who owns the project, go to the Google Cloud Platform Console, open the console left side menu, and click IAM & Admin. Ensure that a project is selected to see the project owner. Try this once and let me know

Comment: @BakulMitra I am experiencing the same issue as OP. I have tried to do what you are suggesting and IAM & Admin can not be opened for a project in question. The error message that is displayed is: `You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page`

Comment: Refer to this particular [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70541593/15745106) which looks similar to the issue you are facing. Let me know if this solves your problem.